# GCC transparent union

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, unions

So I have a union defined like:

```
typedef union
{
   uint8_t  *b1;
   uint16_t *b2;
   uint32_t *b3;
   uint64_t *b4;
} buffer_u __attribute__((__transparent_union__));
```

And a functions defined like:

```
int write_byte_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint8_t val);
int write_short_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint16_t val);
int write_int_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint32_t val);
int write_long_long_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint64_t val);
```

Then I am invoking it like:

```
uint8_t buffer[1024];
write_long_long_to_buffer(buffer, 1024, some_value);
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
error: conversion from ‘uint8_t*’ to non-scalar type ‘buffer_u’ requested
```

Why am I getting this error? I must be reading the documentation on the **transparent_union** attribute incorrectly because I would expect any of the union member types to be able to be passed in where a buffer_u is expected.

I am trying to avoid using a void * for the buffer type, or different pointer types for each function, but may have to fall back to that.

One more useful bit of information. The code is C, but the code using the library is C++.

Is there something special about C++ that doesn't allow this?

Comment: Compilers might (should) ignore transparent union attribute when the members do not represent the same amount of memory. In your case each of the members use up a different number of bytes in memory so transparent union is probably bound to fail.

Comment: @SpectreVert Not true here, the members are all pointers that should have the same representation.

Comment: @lk Ah right I misread. In that case it seems OP's gcc is either broken or old. Still, I cannot see any interest in using a transparent union for pointers as they all refer to the same data type.

Comment: @SpectreVert It seems they are using g++, which doesn't support transparent_union.  Using transparent_union is still safer than the alternative of a void pointer, when there are only a few pointer types possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As we could find out, G++ does not support `__transparent_union__`.

I think you will need to typecast all of it, also, for better practice, use a flag to specify which data the union is filled with:

```
struct s_buffer_u
{
    enum e_pointer_width { width8, width16, width32, width64 } width;
    union
    {
       uint8_t  *b1;
       uint16_t *b2;
       uint32_t *b3;
       uint64_t *b4;
    } buffer_u_internal;
}
typedef struct s_buffer_u _buffer_u;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently g++ doesn't really care about the __transparent_union__ attribute. It works fine if compiling a straight C application but when using g++ there are problems

Comment: Basically, you should assume that the GNU C extensions aren't supported in C++ (except when they actually are C++).

Answer (score 0):

Mate, this code worked for me:

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union
{
   uint8_t  *b1;
   uint16_t *b2;
   uint32_t *b3;
   uint64_t *b4;
} buffer_u __attribute__((__transparent_union__));

int write_byte_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint8_t val) {return 0;}
int write_short_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint16_t val) {return 0;}
int write_int_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint32_t val) {return 0;}
int write_long_long_to_buffer(buffer_u buf, uint16_t length, uint64_t val) {return 0;}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint8_t p[100];
    write_byte_to_buffer(p, 1, 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Gcc version:
    fanl@ubuntu-StiDesktop:~$ gcc --version
    gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
    Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Maybe it is your implementation of `write_long_long_to_buffer`, Why are you passing a char pointer to the long_long function?

What is your GCC version and compilation flags?

Comment: gcc version 4.4.7 and the only compile flags are -Wall -Werror at this point. I have a buffer that needs to be filled in with various sized data. This buffer can sometimes be different sizes (not multiple of 8 bytes) so the uint8_t buf[xxx] is used. Also the writing the long long was just an example. The others will be used as well. Right now my invocation is just in some unit tests and I haven't made the rest ofthe application.

Comment: Apparently it is something with C++ as g++ doesn't like yours either. The code is part of a library I am working on. The library is written in C but the unit tests I am also writing are using a C++ framework (hence using g++)

Comment: Glad we found the reason. I recommend you change your pattern instead dropping the CppUTest, in case you are wondering.